# Is the wife obliged to obey every halal command of the husband?

Tags: wife

On some websites like Islamqa.info, Islamqa.org, and so on, I found that serving a husband is obligatory for a wife if what he orders is permissible(halal). Does it mean that if he orders her how and what to cook, sleep, sit, make, and do, do that, take it from here to there, move it, stand there, sit there, and so on as long as it doesn't contradict Shariah?
If what he orders halal, is the wife obligated to obey in every order?

Please answer with reference to hadiths and fatwas that I can read in English or translate in English.

Comment: Some scholars hold that she is obligated to obey every command which does not violate her own rights, does not harm her and which is halal itself. While others hold that she is only obligated to obey the commands which relate to fulfillment of sexual desire.

Comment: @UmH , thank you for your answer. I really need to get it clear. Can you write an answer about the 2nd view you said? Whats the majority's opinion and  give references

Comment: @UmH, can you provide refs of 'others hold that she is only obligated to obey the commands which relate to fulfillment of sexual desire' kindly?

Answer (score 2):

Husband commanding his wife to sit and stand whole day ( or any other illogical order) is not at all *permissible.* The Qur'an says :

> O you who have believed, it is not lawful for you to inherit women by compulsion. And do not make difficulties for them in order to take [back] part of what you gave them unless they commit a clear immorality. **And live with them in kindness.** [Al-Nisa:19]

Hence, if a husband treats his wife without kindness, he is disobeying the command of Allah, which is certainly **NOT permissible**.

Comment: sorry brother. still he has a chance to do what i said above. he can discipline wife 24/7 as long as its halal.

Comment: @FahimKhan What do you mean by discipline ? Please expand your question to make it more illustrative.

Comment: What is the meaning of obedience to a husband? Does the wife have to obey every order given by husband as long as it doesn't contradict Islam? Can he discipline her all time? Can he tell her to do it do that take it put it get it etc? And she is obligated to follow it as long as she is capable and doesnt contradict shariah?
I have some resources which suports this. If you will to give me your discord id, i really want to have  a converstation with you since i have noticed that you have the power to provide some references

Comment: @FahimKhan  The Quran explicitly says to treat wife with kindness. How can a man be kind to his women and follow shariah if he commands and torture her to do illogical things like commanding where to sit and stand , stand and sit whole day etc etc. ? A wife is a wife and human, not a robot toy.

Comment: @FahimKhan No, I don't use discord. Moreover, if you have such things to talk , then prefer to do so in room chats instead of main site.  Comments are only meant to ask for clarifications regarding the Q/A. Thanks !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145353/discussion-between-fahim-khan-and-an-elephant).

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question; just because giving such an order might be a mistake and/or sin on the husband, that doesn't necessarily mean that the wife should disobey it.

Comment: @goldPseudo I am not sure that why should a wife not disobey if the order is having sin or mistake ? ( Disobey here does not necessarily mean something radical, but a polite refusal )